# Runtime Scaling

Tags: game-engine

My game requires the game area to reduce in size after a certain amount of time. That would mean scaling the object at runtime.

Is it possible to scale an object at runtime in Blender game engine?

Comment: You can certainly animate the object's scale and use the *action* actuator to play the animation in the game engine. However, only the display will update. the physics will still work from the original size mesh. A workaround to this would be to have (assuming your arena is a rectangular object) To have a separate object for each wall, and animate them moving toward the center. If you play the animation on each wall piece, the physics will respond to the moving objects.

Comment: I did try the action "actuator", but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I have a text object which has the "Timer property". It has an "Always sensor" connected to a python script for displaying this timer value. Then I created a "Property sensor" for the text object and connected it to the "Action actuator" representing the scaling inwards of the game area. But when I run the game, there is no change in the game area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to scale an object at runtime in Blender game engine?

you can scale an object via Python with [`KX_GameObject.worldScale`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_9/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html#bge.types.KX_GameObject.worldScale)

example:

```
import bge

bge.logic.getCurrentController().owner.worldScale = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to scale an object at runtime in Blender game engine?

You can play an action with a scale channel.

[image]

Example implemention:

[image]

[image]